# Laravel 8 user table column names

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8 with an existing user table. All is working as expected except the password reset link functionality. This is because my table has the email column name as "Email" instead of "email." Other applications use this table, so the column name cannot be changed. I can get the password reset link functionality working if I manually set the column name within the framework itself (example below).

**File: /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php**

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // framework code that retieves the user record for email address

    if ($res) {
        $res->email = $res->Email;
    }

    // rest of frame work code
}
```

This seems a little "hacky." Is there a better approach to this?

Laravel would benefit greatly from more customization regarding the user's table (custom user table name, column names, etc.).

Comment: just copy these working code and past in controller this will be overwrite

Comment: what starter kit are you using for the auth scaffolding?

Comment: "Laravel would benefit greatly from more customisation in regards to the user's table (custom user table name, column names etc)." there is basicly nothing you can not customize in Laravel, you can argue if it is optimal. But then read the documentation first.

Comment: Reading the source I cannot see anywhere in [EloquentUserProvider](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/EloquentUserProvider.php) where it relies on `email` rather than `Email` I think this is all delegated to the authentication code which ships as boilerplate but is modifiable and not part of the framework code

Comment: You can create custom function and call it depend on flag.

Comment: @mrhn any authentication starter kit i've used doesn't allow for you to specify column headings for example. The alternative is to build your own custom authentication.

Comment: @lagbox I'm using a basic breeze implementation

Comment: @apokryfos the source itself doesn't directly state email. The methods that use `retrieveByCredentials` assume "email" is set.

Comment: you control the data that is passed around, these are your controllers and views, you could change 'email' to 'Email' if you wanted to ... and you can adjust the `getEmailForPasswordReset` method on the model

Comment: @steve the methods that assume that are not part of the framework, they are part of the boilerplate that is included in the laravel/ui package and those you can modify without having to modify the framework code. (You don't even need to use that package at all you can implement your own controllers and views from scratch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Laravel` has `mutators` and `accessors`. This does that you can change behavior of ->email access or assigning it. Add this snippet to your `User.php` model.

```
class User {
    public function getEmailAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['Email'];
    }
}
```

You can read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) about it. The naming convention for the function is `get{PropertyName}Attribute`, if you define your function like so, you can easily overwrite property logic in `Laravel`. Making it use the `column Email`.

Comment: This should probably be paired with a `setEmailAttribute` to update the correct column as well

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.